# How to validate user agains policy in code in aspnet core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

All tutorials I've seen show you how to protect action just by adding

```
[Authorize(Policy = "admin")]
```

to controller or action.

But, rather than throwing error, I need to return to browser (in json) the answer to the question if someone is an "admin" 
and none of sources tells how to do that.
Yes you can check claim (User.HasClaim), but policies are made of multiple claims.

So how do I do that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/views?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In the constructor of your controller you can take a dependency on IAuthorizationService authorizationService to have it injected. Then you can use that to check if the user meets the policy like this:

```
var isAuthorized = await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "admin");
```

where "admin" is the name of the policy

Comment: Can you tell me how to get ClaimsPrincipal for any user name, please?

Comment: HttpContext.User or just User is the claims principal, it is intrinsically available inside a controller assuming the controller inherits from ControllerBase.  This is the current user of the request, getting other users based on user name depends on your implementation how to get the user info from the db, then converting that to claimsprincipal is another task.

Comment: Exactly We have AD users. How to create claimsprinciple from these?

Comment: typically we only create claims principal for the current user not for other users. with cookie auth and aspnet identity when the user logs in a claimsprincipal is created by IUserClaimsPrincipleFactory, then it gets serialized into the auth cookie, then on each request the cookie auth middleware deserializes it back into the claims principal for the user.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/views?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 0):

First, let me say this: **The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43231943/4251427) is the correct way of doing this.** Injecting `IAuthorizationService` in the constructor of the controller and then calling this:

```cs
var isAuthorized = await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User, "admin"); // where admin = policy name
```

---

But in my project I'm ended up using a different solution. Because I needed to check `isAuthorized` within a getter. `AuthorizeAsync` is async and async properties are not allowed in C#. Here is my solution:

I wrote a ClaimsPrincipalExtension:

```cs
public static class ClaimsPrincipalExtension
{
    public static bool IsAdminPolicyAuthorized(this ClaimsPrincipal? user)
    {
        if (user is null) return false;

        var allConditionsMet = false;

        // check all the claims and conditions you want to check
        // ...
        // allConditionsMet = your code goes here
        // ...
        
        return allConditionsMet;
    }
}
```

And within the `AuthorizationHandler` I just call the extension:

```cs
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AdminAuthorizedRequirement requirement)
{
    var isAuthorized = context.User.IsAdminPolicyAuthorized();
    if (isAuthorized) context.Succeed(requirement);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Now I can call the extension wherever I need it like this:

```cs
var isAuthorized = User.IsAdminPolicyAuthorized();
```